# Jasperreports and iReport upgrade compatibility

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I`ve been working with Jasperreports for many years now and many versions have been released.

My question is: i have two simple reports in Jasper using version 4.0.2. I tried to upgrade my iReport to version 4.7.1 and even compiling it again, i got a `NullPointerException`.

I upgraded jasperreports to version 4.7.1 and now it works fine.

These kind of errors are very common when upgrading iReport version. Why can`t iReport compile reports to a lower version release? Is it so difficult to mantain such compatibility?

Has anyone had this issue before? What is the risk to upgrade iReport and Jasperreports constantly in a project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not a surprise that your "old" Jasper is not able to handle the "new" report templates.
You can try to avoid this by not upgrading iReport (as there is no reason to, if you are only working with one version).

But if you need to maintain reports that are being executed on differen JasperReports versions, iReport has a downward compatibility mode that can be accessed via extras -> options -> General tab -> Compatibility.

Hope this helps.

From my experience it's not necessary to constantly upgrade JasperReports or iReport, if you are not running into issues and don't need the new features provided in newer versions.
"Never touch a running system."

Comment: Disagree, not upgrading components is a short term gain long term loss. Eventually there will be a new feature that people "must have", and then you will have a month of crap as you try to move everything forward 5 versions.